# How to efficiently extract valid numerical data from text using python?

Tags: nltk, python-3.6

I have a sentence like this: "This is a number 123 based on another number 45.12 as well as some number thirteen and all are available in calendar year 2017"

What is the recommended approach to extract all numerical datapoints (integers, floats and word numbers i.e. 123, 45.12, 'thirteen') from this text but excluding any dates (i.e. 2017)? I am trying to avoid using regex unless absolutely necessary. Can this be done using NLTK?

Thanks.